# import fire is not working after pip install fire (python)

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I installed pip install fire in my terminal in base and in Dev git/bash and want to access fire in Visual Studio Code.

For some reason I'm not able to access the import fire feature.  I am trying to access it in Visual Studio Code.  When I run the code I get the following error:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'fire'

I was expecting to be able to access the fire module after installing it.  I am using Visual Studio Code.

I have tried many different things even speaking to the TA's in my Coding Bootcamp but nothing is working.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like you installed it for a different version of python than visual studio is using.  Update the question to show these two things: The output of the `pip --version` command, and running this code in visual studio: `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Answer (score 0):

Please check which python interpreter you are using from the bottom-right of the VSCode.

[image]

And where you have installed the `fire` module. You can through `pip show fire` or `conda list fire` to get it.

[image]

Then you can switch the python interpreter, or reinstall the `fire` module again in the environment which you have selected.

[image]